# Side effects when optimize webpack with Angular2

Tags: angular, webpack

I am trying to perform

```
webpack --optimize-minimize
```

on my Angular2 SPA and getting the following errors like these.

```
WARNING in ./wwwroot/dist/bundle.js from UglifyJs
Side effects in initialization of unused variable OPERATORS [./~/angular2/src/co
re/change_detection/parser/lexer.js:422,0]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable freeExports [./~/rxjs/util/roo
t.js:12,0]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable freeModule [./~/rxjs/util/root
.js:13,0]
Dropping unused variable _CONTEXT_ACCESSOR [./~/angular2/src/core/change_detecti
on/codegen_name_util.js:6,0]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable ViewType [./~/angular2/src/cor
e/linker/view_type.js:12,0]
Dropping unused variable __unused [./~/angular2/src/common/pipes/async_pipe.js:3 ...
```

My webpack.config.js is this

```
module.exports = {
  "entry": "./Angular/boot",
  "output": {
    "filename": "./wwwroot/dist/bundle.js"
  },
  "resolve": {  
    "extensions": [ '', '.js', '.ts' ]
  },
  "module": {
    "loaders": [
      {
        "test": /\.ts/,
        "loaders": [ 'ts-loader' ],
        "exclude": /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

When running the page I get a 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' so there is some circular referencing going on with the minified javascript.

Help appreciated, many thanks

Comment: Hello, I have exactly the same problem, do you found any solution?

Comment: Damn I wish I posted the answer but I have tried to remember from reading my question but I do not know what the solution was. Sorry.  Maybe make sure everything is up to date.